# how to put the loop valuable in a json body on unix command?

Tags: bash

In Linux, I am trying to do something on command as:

```
for i in {1..10}
do  
    let i=i*10 
    curl -X POST http://server/MyApiCall -d'{"x": $i, "y": 0}' 
done
```

Currently it does not work, as "**$i**" is not valid in this json body. Does anyone the correct format for that ?

Thanks.

Comment: `-d'{"x": '"$i"', "y": 0}'`

Comment: Substitution is not performed within single-quoted strings.